# java printing an array with Arrays.toString() error

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

So I was trying to print an array of ints in my program, and following these instructions [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

wrote the following code:

```
    int[] totals = //method that returns int array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(totals));
```

But it wont compile saying that

> "method toString in class Object cannot be applied to given types. 
>   required: no arguments
>   found: int[]
>   reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length"

Why does it do that? Do I not pass my array as an argument to toString? If not, how do I use toString?

Thank you!

Comment: looks fine to me. Test with an array like this: `int[] totals = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };`

Comment: are you getting any other compiler errors or warnings?

Comment: No, I wasn't getting any other errors. But the two answers bellow helped me out. My main class was named Arrays (neubie mistake), so it was confused what I was referencing when I wrote Arrays.toString(totals). Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> method toString in class Object cannot be applied to given types. required: no arguments found: int[] reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length

May be you have a variable named `Arrays`, that's why the compiler is complaining thinking that you are trying to invoke the `Object.toString()`, which doesn't take any argument.

Try

```
 System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(totals));
```

Comment: Maybe you have a variable named Arrays? Common! My answer was downvoter for less :)

Comment: As I just commented above I called the class for this program Arrays, so that's probably it. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Also thank you for that workaround! I used it instead of having to rename the class. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it says "method toString in class Object cannot be applied to given types." makes me think you might not be importing the `java.util.Arrays` class properly, or you have some other object called `Arrays`.

Comment: or rather: he's got a _variable_ named `Arrays`: `Object Arrays = null`

Comment: I called the class for this program Arrays. That must be it, so I'll just rename the class. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
int[] totals = {1,2};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(totals));
```

printing:

```
[1, 2]
```

Are you sure you use at least **JDK 5** ?

Indeed, `Arrays.toString(int[] a)` only exists since JDK 5.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you try ::

```
int[] totals = //method that returns int array
    System.out.println(totals.toString());
```

Comment: `toString()` on an array won't do anything useful: it just prints the reference for the array. The OP wants to use the `Arrays` class to print each value.

Comment: If you try this for arrays: it will print the comma separated data

Comment: Yeah I tried this as well before posting this question, it printed the memory address.

Answer (score -1):

Your method doesn't seem to init your array, try this:

```
int[] totals = new int[10]; //method that returns int array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(totals));
```

Comment: If the array hadn't been initialised, I wouldn't expect the argument exception.